# Cannot connect Wi-Fi because of previous password

Tags: windows-7

My brother changed the password of the Wi-Fi that I had used to connect my laptop. When he left to another city he changed the password of the Wi-Fi. I know the password but I'm unable to connect to the internet connection because there is a previously saved password.

How can I remove old password and add new password?

Answer (score 13):

The best way would be to delete or "forget" the network and connect to it fresh.

To delete a wireless network connection in Windows 7:

1. Start Network and Sharing Center.
2. In the Tasks pane, click Manage wireless networks.
3. Right-click the connection you want to delete, and then click Remove network.
4. In the Manage Wireless Networks - Warning dialog box, click OK.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252588%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply change the password after clicking on wireless networks double click on the wireless network you need to connect to and click on the security tab. Change the password.

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer?